# Search for packages from Ubuntu repositories whose names start with g++-

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, apt, g++

There are multiple versions of g++ packages in the default Ubuntu repositories. I already know that the package names of the packages that I am searching for all start with *g++-*, but searching for these packages with `apt-cache search g++-` returns many unhelpful search results that don't start with *g++-* because the `g++-` string in `apt-cache search g++-` is a regular expression. How to search only for packages whose names start with *g++-*?

My available Ubuntu versions to test the command are 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04, but if you have some other OS that has apt command-line package manager I will try the command in Ubuntu and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchoring and escaping the special character `+` like in a regular expression works:

```
# apt-cache search '^g\+\+-'
g++-7 - GNU C++ compiler
g++-7-multilib - GNU C++ compiler (multilib support)
g++-aarch64-linux-gnu - GNU C++ compiler for the arm64 architecture
...
```

(A visual scan didn't show any packages that didn't begin with `g++` in the output.)

Tested in Docker containers running 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04.